# Open a record using token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, token

I'm building a RoR app where each record has a unique, 7 character token (hex). I would like to create link on a page where a user can provide that token and be brought to the edit path for that record.  I've scoured the WWW and can't seem to find a clean method to accomplish this task.

Any ideas?

I realize I run a slight risk of duplication, but this will be a novelty app more than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Vanity URLs in Rails**

For if you want to be able to navigate to `/model/5na09zn` instead of `/model/{id}`:

> **1. `config/routes.rb`**

```
resources :model
```

*--- becomes --->*

```
resources :model, :except => ['show', 'update', 'destroy']

get    'posts/:hex_token' => 'model#show', :as => 'model'
put    'posts/:hex_token' => 'model#update'
delete 'posts/:hex_token' => 'model#destroy'
```

> **2. `app/controllers/model.rb`**
>
> ***Do this for all show, update and destroy:***
>
> *(Better yet, write a controller function to handle this automatically!)*

```
def show
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])
       ...
end
```

*--- becomes --->*

```
def show
    @model = Model.find_by_hex_token(params[:model])    
       ...
end
```

Comment: I like your plan, but I don't think it will work in this use case.  Well, I'm not using a vanity URL (yet).  Instead, the hex code is saved in the db along with the other inputs.  The hex code will be hidden from the user and e-mailed to an admin.  I'd like for the admin to be able to go to the homepage and type in '5na09zn' into a form field and be directed to the edit page of that record (assuming they're logged in)

Comment: So you want, like, a password protected edit page? You might want to update your question